# In XML serialisation, can properties be serialised as an attribute of a new element?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a class with a similar structure to:

```
[XmlRoot("myclass")]
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlElement("subject")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("object")]
    public string Object { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming `Subject = "Me"` and `Object = "You"`, this would serialise to:

```
<myclass>
  <subject>Me</subject>
  <object>You</object>
</myclass>
```

Is there a way to serialise to the following XML, preferably using XML serialisation attributes and avoiding new custom types:

```
<myclass>
  <subject value="Me" />
  <object value="You" />
</myclass>
```

Comment: What are you using to serialize?

Comment: The `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating a class that uses the [`XmlAttributeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I included implicit conversion from `T` so that you can continue to use concise syntax like `new MyClass { Subject = "Me", Object = "You" }`

```
[XmlRoot("myclass")]
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlElement("subject")]
    public ValueAttribute<string> Subject { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("object")]
    public ValueAttribute<string> Object { get; set; }
}
public class ValueAttribute<T>
{
    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator ValueAttribute<T>(T value)
    {
        return new ValueAttribute<T> { Value = value };
    }
}
```

This produces something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<myclass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <subject value="Me" />
  <object value="You" />
</myclass>
```